# package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime does not exist in AWS java sdk 1.10.2

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I am trying the Java code example in the [Getting Started (Authoring AWS Lambda Code in Java)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-gs.html) page, but am stuck as **com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime** pacakge seems to be missing

Here is the sample code:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;      //package does not exist error
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger; // package does not exist error
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;       // import works (not needed, I've put them in for testing import)
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object; // import works (not needed, I've put them in for testing import)

public class Hello {
    public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received : " + myCount);
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}
```

I encounter the same error both in Netbeans and through command line (specifying the aws sdk thorugh -cp argument) from the first two imports of the code:

> package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime does not exist

Note importing other packages from the SDK works fine, as per third and fourth imports from the above code (the s3 imports which i put in just to test).

I am using version **1.10.2** (aws-java-sdk-1.10.2.zip) of the AWS Java SDK, downloaded from http://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip

Any directions/suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Both of those classes are contained in the [aws-lambda-java-core](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.amazonaws%7Caws-lambda-java-core%7C1.0.0%7Cjar) jar, which is distributed separately from the AWS SDK. You can download it from maven central at the link above if you're not using maven/gradle/some other build system that can natively pull from maven central.

Comment: Thanks David - I struggled to find the download link from AWS, but was able to get it from Maven as per your advice and the import not works!  Cheers.

Comment: @David- I am also facing a similar problem. When I am staring the app from the terminal using the cmd - 'sam local start-api' . It works fine but when I start by right clicking on the 'template.yml' file. It gives this error

Answer (score 8):

1. Add AWS plugins within eclipse from market place, make aws lambda project.
2. Use below three dependencies to make fat jar.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
       <version>1.11.76</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
   </dependency> 
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

After some searching I found com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core/1.1.0 . (I prefer this site to search.maven.org. mvnrepository.com gets right to the heart of my problem by supplying the sbt build line.)

The class is not in aws-java-sdk-lambda , nor is it in aws-java-sdk-core, or aws-java-sdk .

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.241",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.2.0"
)
```

Check the links for the lastest version:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core

Answer (score 1):

Arthur,

You trying use java code sample from [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-gs.html) for another product Amazon [AWS SDK For Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-setup.html).

Please read AWS Lambda welcome-page and maybe after steps for (create account and others) you can to download package with your classes (Context, LambdaLogger)

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: Thanks Battr for clarifying the difference between AWS SDK library and AWS Lambda library.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution for intellij was delete all `.iml` files and `invalidate cache/restart.`

Answer (score 0):

I found com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger in: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-log4j/1.0.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In addition, this is the package you need to include if you want the sample Lamba Functions from the Alexa skills SDK to log to CloudWatch.